# easy javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have a problem with the following code. I'm trying to get a random string from my array to be displayed when a button is clicked.

```
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var div = document.getElementById("box");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var array=[ "thanks for clicking", "keep on clicking", "click one more time", "why do you keep on clicking me?", "stop clicking me!"];
function thing(){
    var y = array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length)+1)];
    text.value=y;
}

function what(){
    text.value = "what";    
}
</script>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" onClick="what()" />
</form>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text" value="hey" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: Move the script below the `<form>`

Comment: when do you ever call thing()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found couple of issues here.

You have two form tags which is un-necessary and the form tags needs to have a name and id. Atleast name attribute must be there.

Check the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ayyadurai/3Ru9T/

```
  <form name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="click" onClick="what()" />

   <input type="text" id="text" value="hey" />
  </form>




var button = document.getElementById("button");
var div = document.getElementById("box");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var array=[ "thanks for clicking", "keep on clicking", "click one more time", "why do you keep on clicking me?", "stop clicking me!"];


function thing(){
var y = array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length)+1)];
form1.text.value=y;
```

}

```
function what(){
form1.text.value = "what"; 
            thing();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your javascript block to below the form.

When you set:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
```

The element doesn't exist yet.  If you move your script block below the form, then the element will exist before the javascript is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations are not going to work - and also you are not calling the method to place the random item from the array in place.

This will work:

```
<script>
    function thing() {
        var array = ["thanks for clicking", "keep on clicking", "click one more time", "why do you keep on clicking me?", "stop clicking me!"];

        var y = array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length) + 1)];
        document.getElementById("text").value = y;
    }

    function what() {
        document.getElementById("text").value = "what";
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="click" onclick="thing()" />
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text" value="hey" />
    </form>
</body>
```